# How to resolve AbstractMethod Error in blob encryption?

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, abstractmethoderror

I want to upload blob into azure blob storage by applying encryption for it. so i have tried to do it using following code:

```
 File f=new File("/home/prospera-user15/Desktop/test/download.jpeg");

        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
        // Container name must be lower case.
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("upload1");
        container.createIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("megha");
        final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(2048);
        final KeyPair wrapKey = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        RsaKey key = new RsaKey("RSA",wrapKey);
        System.out.println("Uploading the encrypted blob.");
        BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(key, null);
        BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
        options.setEncryptionPolicy(policy);
        AccessCondition accessCondition = null;
        OperationContext opContext = null;
        try{
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(f), f.length(), accessCondition, options, opContext);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch (StorageException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        }
```

[image: for above code i got following exception:]

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

[`AbstractMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) implies *the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since last compilation*

In your case, you might be using old version of an interface implementation which is missing a new interface method and as per stacktrace that might be your `RsaKey` class/interface.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

Source:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

Have you also tried to check if you have authorized your application to use the key or secret per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#authorize) ?